# After prevent direct link access without login, JSON is not working

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

My code was running well, when i use this piece of code-

```
public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['login'])){

        redirect('welcome');
    }
}
```

then in view-

```
<?php
   $url = site_url('user/category/showCategoryJson'); // path to your JSON file
   $data = file_get_contents($url); // put the contents of the file into a variable
   $results = json_decode($data,true); // decode the JSON feed
   foreach ($results[0] as $key => $cat) { 
?>
  <tr class="odd gradeX">
   <td><?php echo $cat['categoryname']; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $cat['username']; ?></td>   
   <td class="center"><a class="btn btn-success fa fa-edit editcat" id="<?php echo $cat['categoryid']; ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal<?php echo $cat['categoryid']; ?>"></a> <a class="btn btn-danger fa fa-trash delete" id="<?php echo $cat['categoryid']; ?>"></a></td>
  </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Getting error. But if I just ignore the code inside constructor all things are working perfectly. Can you please suggest me what should i do.

Here is the function, which I am calling in view-

```
public function showCategoryJson(){
    $this->load->model('user/category_model');
    $data[] = $this->category_model->displayCategory();
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Both constructor and showCategoryJson() function in same controller.

Here is the picture of error-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are constructing an HTTP URL to fetch your JSON from your own server.

Since you have to login before you can get data, and your PHP script (acting as a client) hasn't logged into your server: You can't fetch the data that way.

Forget about JSON. Just access the data directly from your database.

```
$this->load->model('user/category_model');
$results[] = $this->category_model->displayCategory();
foreach ($results[0] as $key => $cat) {
```

Comment: Thanks for your rapid answer. Yes it works, I have already applied this technique, before i post this question. That mean there is no way? :(

Comment: You could write your PHP so it logs in to the server (how you do that would depend on how your login system works). Assuming they are the same server, that would be grossly overcomplicated and inefficient.